# How Can I Center JLabel using NetBeans Gui Builder?

Tags: java, netbeans

After long time i have decided to switch back to Java NetBeans Gui builder. I want to create Management System and keep it professional in terms of User Interface. However am having problem centering the JLabel. My Label takes the full width of the panel and panel is resizable. I want my Label to be resizable and to be centered no matter the size my window. Is this possible? Please I don't want hard coding am using netbeans Gui builder. How can I achieve this? For your information my reputations are too low to post images so nothing to show right now.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seemed to work for me.

1. Drag a panel into your design
2. Right-click the panel and check the menu checkboxes : Auto Resizing-> Horizontal , and Auto Resizing -> Vertical
3. Drag a label as the only component
4. Select the panel. Right-click -> Set Layout -> Border Layout
5. Select the label. Right-click -> Properties
6. Choose Center for the both horizontalAlignment and verticalAlignment.

Comment: Thanks it has worked. I have really really appreciated.. In your second option, i don't need to set auto-Resizing for vertical. Thanks for your helpful answer. nice stay...